# I am trying to make an animation of a double planet, can't seem to get it right.

Tags: modeling, animation

Trying to make an animation of a double planet orbiting their sun and sharing a common barycentre.

How do I go about making this work? [image]

Comment: Could you edit your question and show some examples of what you have tried and what your issues are? We don't make tutorials here, we answer questions :)

Comment: Will the double planets always be diametrically opposed?  And does the planet barycentre orbit align with the sun?

Comment: @batFINGER according to the wiki page there are a great variety of orbits describing this effect, after all its the balance of orbiting mass which includes more than just a planet and moon.

Comment: I would describe what I've tried so far if I knew how  Only installed blender yesterday my only other experience with animation was with flash a looooooong time ago. Sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution is to use an empty (Empty1) as the Moon/Planet barycentre which follows a large path representing the star orbit. The moon and Planet each have a path that follows Empty1 around the Star.

[image: Barycentre demo]

[image: barycentre and planet paths]

Here you can see a Constraint example:

[image: objects and constraint example]

These are the loops indicating days and a year:

[image: Loops of animated orbits, 1 day = 50frames, 1 year = 12*50frames]

Of course the large orbit path should also be eccentric but I doubt that the difference in mass here would be noticeable ;-)

Comment: Thanks The empty thing is what I was trying following a tutorial on YouTube from a guy called Olav ??? But can't get it to work

Answer (score 4):

I know of two ways of going about this:

### Method 1: Using Armatures

This is probably the more flexible and common method, just create an Armature for your solar system, have the root bone be placed in the centre of your sun, then position child bones for where you want things to rotate, in your case, the common barycentre shared by your two planets, after that, go ahead and:

A. parent each planet to the child bone of the barycentre. or

B. assign them each to the vertex group of the bone with an armature modifier.

You can now rotate the bones within the armature to animate orbits.

### Method 2: Using Empties

This is probably less common and flexible, but can be easier to understand, for some.

Create an Empty, parent it to your sun, and place it in the centre of your sun.
Create a second empty for your barycentre, and parent it to your first Empty. Position this empty on a **single** axis, whatever distance you desire it to be from the centre of your sun. Now parent both your planets to your second empty, and position them the desired distance apart from the barycentre on a **single** axis.

You can now rotate the empties to animate orbits.

Comment: Why not just make a couple "orbit' Path curves for the planets to follow (path constraint) then they track an empty around star? You could make the paths follow  barrycentre empty?

Comment: Yes, that'll work, too. It never occurred to me before, though.
It's a much better option, why don't you write your own answer detailing it?

Comment: Because I am lazy and didn't imagine it was a very good solution.

Comment: I've been testing it, and it seems that the curves reach an eventual point where they stop animating, although that may be a result of my lack of knowledge regarding curves.

Answer (score 4):

### Driving follow path fixed offset

---

Edit: code update for 2.8x.  images from 2.79x see [revision history](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/91511/revisions) for 2.7x code.

[image]
*Script results, something similar to earth moon system on left, and eccentric elliptic on right*

**Setting up the double planets**
Set cursor location to (0, 0, 0), add a sphere and an orbit circle. Scale to suit. Add a follow path constraint to the sphere, as shown below.  The target is the orbit circle object.

[image]

The driver can be typed directly into the field, using  a `#` (hash) as first character, eg `#(frame / 50) % 1` or via the drivers panel, without the hash.  The driver expression

```
(frame / 50) % 1
```

is basically making the planet travel the path every 50 frames.

Select both the planet and path and duplicate.  And now the sneaky tricky bit, scale the orbit dupe by -1  <kbd>s</kbd>
 <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> This will ensure the dupe planet is always in opposite phase, or diametrically opposed to original planet.

You can now scale the orbits and planets to suit.  Add both planets and orbits to a group, as a group instance is going to be used when orbiting the double planet.

**Python code setup**

In case that's a bit daunting, here is the code to do same, with the default settings set up something like [90 Antiope in the Gallery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter#Gallery)

[image]

Copy the code block below paste into blender text and run script.

```
import bpy
from math import sqrt
name = "90 Antiope"
planet_size = 0.5
orbit_time = 50 # full orbit frames
orbit_size = (5, 5) # elipse if not same
planet2_scale = 1 # times bigger than planet
orbit2_scale = 1
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
vl = context.view_layer
# cursor to zero
scene.cursor.location = (0, 0, 0)
# make a group for the doubleplants
group = bpy.data.collections.new(name)
scene.collection.children.link(group)
vl.active_layer_collection = vl.layer_collection.children[group.name]
# create 2 planets
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=planet_size)
planet = context.object
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_nurbs_circle_add(radius=1)
orbit = context.object
x, y = orbit_size
orbit.scale.x, orbit.scale.y = x, y
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)
if x != y: # get focus of eliptical path
    axis = 0 if x > y else 1
    scene.cursor.location[axis] = sqrt(abs(x * x - y * y))
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')
    orbit.location = (0, 0, 0)
# follow path
fp = planet.constraints.new('FOLLOW_PATH')
fp.target = orbit
fp.use_fixed_location = True
fp.use_curve_follow = True
# drive the offset
fcurve = fp.driver_add("offset_factor")
fcurve.driver.expression = "(frame / %d) %% 1" % orbit_time
planet2 = planet.copy()

orbit2 = orbit.copy()

# fix target
planet2.constraints[0].target = orbit2
planet2.scale *=  planet2_scale
# give orbit2 a negative scale (diametric)
orbit2.scale *= -1 * orbit2_scale
# link them to group
for o in [planet2, orbit2]:
    group.objects.link(o)
```

Eccentric elliptic orbits (from [gallery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter#Gallery))

[image]

```
name = "Eccentric Elliptic"
planet_size = 0.5
orbit_time = 50 # full orbit frames
orbit_size = (3, 5) # ellipse if not same
planet2_scale = 1 # times bigger than planet
orbit2_scale = 1
```