# Simulating N-bodies gravitational interaction

Tags: force-fields

I wanted to simulate attraction of massive bodies in space and added Force field of type "force"

[image]

Unfortunately, all these bodies stay still on animation.

(I turned gravitation off so that bodies don't fall)

What I did wrong?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118441/gravity-simulation

Comment: @batFINGER sorry didn't understand :(