# initial velocity for simulating planetary motion

Tags: python, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I was going to simulate planetary motion in blender and i have simulated the gravitational attraction between two planets with rigid body and force field.
but i don't have any idea about how to give one of them initial velocity with physical accuracy
If there is a way to do this with python that would be awesome!!

Here is my blender file :
https://gofile.io/d/XnTyAw
[image]

There is a problem with the common trick of giving objects initial velocity because it suddenly disappears :
[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118441/gravity-simulation

Comment: @batFINGER it doesn't work!!! i have added something check it out

Answer (score 0):

an initial velocity in a rigid body simulation is very easy to do:

1. check animated checkbox and keyframe a location
2. keyframe another location on another later frame (distance + keyframe distance will "make" the speed
3. one keyframe later: disable animated checkbox and keyframe it

Comment: I've tried this and the object suddenly vanishes

Comment: that was your question, and that is my answer. of course - if there are some other circumstances like force fields or parenting (like you have) it behaves differently. One problem in your simulation is: you turned gravity on which is in your case - nonsense - because gravity in Blender is in one direction (normally -z - but you can change that). But in your case you don't want that, because you want "space gravity between objects) and not directional gravity(simplified) like on earth.

Comment: It disappears because of gravity in -z direction!!

Comment: so how to fix?(sorry i'm beginner)