# Can I make custom force field that only rotates particles around an object?

Tags: python, particles, physics, mathematics, force-fields

Hi I want to make particles only rotate around an object. And I also want them to follow a simple equation

$$
F \propto {1 \over r^2}
$$

where $r$ is the distance of each particle from the object. Is there any way I can achieve this goal?

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118441/gravity-simulation

Comment: with that I can simulate gravity but if i want to simulate any other force which is kinda like that but its equation is different or value is different, then what can I do?

Comment: Because you need the formula I would try it with drivers and the copy the objects and move them as you need it

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the built-in particles without a serious hack/patch. If the amount of particles is not too large and you only want them to move according to your rules, no interactions, Animation Nodes might be pretty interesting for you.

Comment: how much particles? can you suggest me some good YouTube videos about animation nodes?  @FrederikSteinmetz

Comment: We have some, but they're a bit older, search for blenderdiplom on YT. How many particles they can support depends on your setup and computer. 1000 should be no problem, 10,000 might be somewhat of a limit.