# Planetary system simulation with real orbital datas

Tags: animation

When making a planetary system, I'd like to respect the eccentiricity of orbits (elliptical orbits), using the facts supplied by astronomical data centers like here: http://www.icoproject.org/data.html ?

One of the focus of the ellipse can be set at the center of the planetary system; i.e.the center of the central star.

I have other parameters under control (e.g.speeds, orbits inclinations, period of rotation...).

Thanks in advance for your precious advices!

Comment: There is a question mark in your post but there is no query. Could you clarify what your question is?

Comment: relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **[Orbital Eccentricity - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity)**
>
> For elliptical orbits, a simple proof shows that `arcsin(e)`
> yields the projection angle of a perfect circle
> to an ellipse of eccentricity e. For example, to view the eccentricity
> of the planet Mercury (e = 0.2056), one must simply calculate the
> inverse sine to find the projection angle of 11.86 degrees. Next, tilt
> any circular object (such as a coffee mug viewed from the top) by that
> angle and the apparent ellipse projected to your eye will be of that
> same eccentricity.

Via the UI, add a primitive circle mesh or curve, rotate about X <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>11.86</kbd>, then scale in 0 in Z, <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

[image]
*Result of running test script*

Quick test script, creates a circle, rotates by projection angle about X, projects onto XY plane by setting z to 0.

Could use bmesh, or make the projection matrix.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import asin

def elliptic_orbit(name, e, context=bpy.context):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add()
    R = Matrix.Rotation(asin(e), 4, 'X')
    ob = context.object
    
    me = context.object.data
    ob.name = me.name = "%s_orbit" % name
    me.transform(R)
    for v in me.vertices:
        v.co.z = 0
    me.update()
    
elliptic_orbit("Earth", 0.017)
elliptic_orbit("Mercury", 0.2056).scale *= 0.387  
elliptic_orbit("Venus", 0.007).scale *= 0.723
elliptic_orbit("Mars", 0.093).scale *= 1.524 
elliptic_orbit("Jupiter", 0.048).scale *= 5.203 
elliptic_orbit("Saturn", 0.056).scale *= 9.555
```

Alternatively orbit as a curve. Here I've used a scale matrix to scale z component to zero, could do same in mesh version.

```
def elliptic_orbit(name, e, context=bpy.context):
    bpy.ops.curve.primitive_nurbs_circle_add()
    S = Matrix.Scale(0, 4, (0, 0, 1))
    R = Matrix.Rotation(asin(e), 4, 'X')
    ob = context.object
    
    cu = context.object.data
    ob.name = cu.name = "%s_orbit" % name
    cu.transform(R)
    cu.transform(S)

    return ob
```

For compatability sakes I've applied the transforms sequentially.  For 2.5 K= verson < 2.8  could use `cu.transform(R * S)` and for 2.8 `cu.transform(R @ S)`

**Ellipse foci**

> **[Ellipse - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equation)**
>
> shape parameters: **a**: semi-major axis, **b**: semi-minor axis **c**: linear eccentricity, **p**: semi-latus rectum.
>
> [image: Ellipse-param.svg]
> By [Ag2gaeh](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Ag2gaeh) - Own work, [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=57428275)

The semi-major axis will lie on the rotated axis X. c the linear eccentricity can be calculated thus

```
>>> ob = C.object
>>> ob.name
'Jupiter_orbit'

>>> ob.dimensions.xy.length
0.4994825301958152
```

The two foci are `F1, F2 = (c, 0, 0), (-c, 0, 0)`

May find the following post on [barycentric orbits](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91511/15543) of interest.