# Gravitational Orbit

Tags: animation, physics

I want to make a gravitational orbit simulation using the python interface on blender. I want it to be realistic (kepler orbits). The path should be ellipitcal with the sun at one of the foci and the orbiting planet should speed up when its closer to the sun so as to obey the second law. I am not sure what the best way is to approach this simulation if people have suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Couple of mine that are somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91511/15543  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132925/planetary-system-simulation-with-real-orbital-datas