# Adding A Background Colour

Tags: python, color

My project is the simulation of the solar system. I have completed the orbits of the planets however, the final thing I need to do is to add a background colour of a cluster of colours that represent the galaxy. I wanted to know how to add a galaxy background as part of my project. This needs to be written in python code as part of my project however, if it is easier to not do this in python, it is not a problem at all. Also, making sure that the image is behind the work I have created would be great too!

[image: final result]

Comment: Hi. Please add *much more* detail about what you're asking. Remember, we know nothing about your project or what you need. What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Please use the [edit] link under the question to add more information, including any relevant images. It will be difficult to help you with the information you have given so far. Thanks.

Comment: okay already done!

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44773/stars-background-in-cycles   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8923/how-do-you-use-an-image-as-the-world-background  Good to see some of [my code](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164897/moon-to-move-with-earth) being put to good use.