# Copying a meshes intersecting outline from the top down view

Tags: modeling, modifiers, knife-tool

I have a **sliced shape** that I would like to copy it's **outline** as it's seen from the top down view (**looking straight down on it**).

Example:
I have an equation that is sliced by a plane using the **Intersect** option of the **Boolean modifier**.

[image: img1]

I then want to copy just the outline / Intersection (**the "warped" egg shape circled in red**) that is created when looking at it from the top down view.

[image: img2]

I was looking at the **Knife project** tool but I want the **projection of top down view of a slice.**

I feel like I'm over thinking it.  I'm willing to try a different solution.

Comment: As in copy the edge ring, separate, and shrinkwrap project in Z onto an XY plane or via code set the z coord of each ring vert to a constant.?

Comment: @batFINGER Yes to the first part project Z onto XY.  Not sure what the 2nd "via code set the z cord to a constant" it sounds intriguing (not sure what that will do or how to do that).

Comment: same as first.  XY ground plane is Z=0  hence any coord on that plane is (x, y, 0)

Comment: @batFINGER sounds quicker. I duplicated the edge loop but how does one set each edge to zero so it mimics the "egg" shape?

Comment: set the vert coords.  `for v in youredgeloopobject.data.vertices: v.co.z = 0`  (This assumes that the mesh has no loc rot & unit  scale, _ie_ local and global coords same)  Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132925/planetary-system-simulation-with-real-orbital-datas

Comment: I don't get it. Shift-D copy, followed by SZ0?

Comment: @RobinBetts I knew I was over thinking...At-least I learned new ways to do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Via a script.**

A "conic section script".

Define a plane via its global location and normal.  For example add a plane named "Plane" aligned to cut

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Plane']
```

`plane_co`  Global coordinate.

```
>>> C.object.matrix_world.translation
Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

`plane_no`  Global normal. (its rotation x z axis)

```
>>> C.object.matrix_world.to_3x3() @ Vector((0, 0, 1))
Vector((0.8242384195327759, -0.06781885027885437, 0.5621669292449951))
```

Running this script will bisect the context object (with modifiers and shapekeys applied) using the plane coordinates supplied and create a new segment object.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
from bpy import context

# cutting plane coords and normal (global)

plane_co = (0, 0, 0)
plane_no = (1, 1, 1)
project_to_ground = True

ob = context.object
# object with modifiers shapekeys applied.
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_object(
        ob, 
        context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
        )
        
bm.transform(ob.matrix_world)


bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(
        bm,
        geom=sum((bm.verts[:], bm.edges[:], bm.faces[:]), []),
        plane_no=plane_no,
        plane_co=plane_co,
        clear_inner=True,
        clear_outer=True,
        )
        
me = bpy.data.meshes.new(f"{ob.name}_Section")
bm.to_mesh(me)
if project_to_ground:
    me.transform(Matrix.Scale(0, 4, (0, 0, 1)))
new_ob = bpy.data.objects.new(f"{ob.data.name}_Section", me)

context.collection.objects.link(new_ob)
```

Related

[Planetary system simulation with real orbital datas](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132925/planetary-system-simulation-with-real-orbital-datas)

[How to extract side-view outline (e.g. top view) of a 3D object to 2D surface?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121119/how-to-extract-side-view-outline-e-g-top-view-of-a-3d-object-to-2d-surface)