# Make an object orbit another object indefinitely

Tags: modeling, animation, materials, modifiers, sculpting

I am trying to make a moon orbit a planet.
I am capable of tracking a camera, however this seems different as I want to animation to continue at the same rate throughout the animation.

I have tried to add a new CURVE => CIRCLE. Then ADD CONSTRAINT, FOLLOW TRACK. however this does not work.. There is no option to track my circle/curve/path created.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91511/15543

Comment: I have tried that, but there is no FOLLOW PATH

Comment: Boy that seems a bit OTT over what is merely a suggested link, not a downvote not a close vote.  . Copying, pasting and running the script in link posted sets up a couple of spheres  and paths as orbits using a follow path constraint and animated  with drivers such that they constantly orbit.  Examine the result and will see to  setup is pretty simple.  (As is the other answer that shows how constantly orbit using keyframes.)  Would also say there is a big difference between something that doesn't work and not being able to work something out.

Comment: Why downvote my post? I don't think its over the top. But its not within context so I removed my post asking why you downvoted it, and my reasons for posting. Apologies if you were offended by me asking why.

Comment: Frankly I have no idea what you are talking about?

Comment: Please don't just repeat the link. It not helpful. Thank you though.

Comment: I really struggle with animating curve paths, so I feel your pain. This is why I like to try to think of alternative approaches. Would it work to create an empty at the center of the orbited object  and then parent the orbiting object to it? Then go into Local Transform Orientation, select the empty, and simply give it a keyframe along one of its axes? It seems to me that given the simplicity of what you are trying to do, curve paths aren't strictly necessary, since your course is fixed in a permanent and perfect circle. So I'm thinking this would work.

Comment: @JamesJameson What downvotes are you talking about? Your question has absolutely no votes, up or down. If you keep antagonizing people trying to point you to relevant posts you will quickly find no one else left willing to help you. If a link is not helpful politely thank the user and explain how it doesn't help so a relevant solution can be reached.

Answer (score 1):

So my understanding is that you are attempting to make an object orbit around another one. In order to have this happen, the general workflow is to first make an Empty at the pivot point, parent an object to it, and then animate the Empty.

Here is how to do it:

1. Select the "center" object (the one the moon would orbit around) by clicking on it.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and select "cursor to selected". That way, when we create the Empty (the point the moon will orbit around), it will be located on the Planet's origin.
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and add an Empty -> Plain Axes.
4. Select the Moon, then Shift-Click the Plain Axes and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, and select "Keep Transform". This will make any transformations applied to the Plain Axes also apply to the Moon.
5. Now keyframe animate the Plane Axes however you want, and it will animate the Moon as it spins. Maybe add a Cycles Modifier to the animation graph so that it will repeat it forever.

Here is a quick gif that shows this entire process:

[image]