# Scientifically correct simulation?

Tags: python, physics

I have been meaning to create an earth - moon simulation, my plan for the effects of gravity was to use the a negative value for the force field. But does that accurately follow gravity. Does the force decrease as 1/r^2?

If not, what is the best way to create that simulation

Comment: The keyword your looking for appears to be "N-body simulation".

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91511/15543  _ie_ the barycentric orbit created due to  effect of gravity between the two.t