# How to I make two objects spiral together, such as in a binary star system?

Tags: system

I am trying to make a simulation of two stars colliding. I can't seem to figure out how to make them spiral together, the way stars would.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91455/i-am-trying-to-make-an-animation-of-a-double-planet-cant-seem-to-get-it-right

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.